# Is there a reasonable notion of universal cover for schemes over arbitrary fields?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fundamental-group, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be smooth projective variety, such as an elliptic curve. We know that $X$ does not have a universal cover in the category of schemes.

However, if $k = \mathbf{C}$, then $\tilde{X}$ exists as a complex manifold. For example, $\tilde{X} \cong \mathbf{C} \longrightarrow X \cong \mathbf{C}/\Lambda$ for an elliptic curve.

What about $k = \mathbf{F}_q$ or $k = \mathbf{Q}_p$? Does a universal cover for $X$ exist in some appropriate$^\ast$ category?

($\ast$) One which interacts with the algebraic geometry of $X$ in a meaningful way.

Comment: something like Tate uniformization is potentially relevant.

Comment: Sixty years ago Tate showed the answer is yes for an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ whose reduction mod p has a node with tangents rational over the base field. Since then there has been a huge amount of work. For a brief friendly introduction, see Section 3 of Milne's article "The Work of John Tate", available on his webpage jmilne.org/math/ under Expository Notes.

Comment: So there is no general construction yet for a smooth projective scheme over $\mathbf{Q}_q$? Is there any consensus on whether such a thing should exist?

Comment: @anon's link, clickably:  [Milne - The work of John Tate](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/Tate.pdf).

Comment: You may enjoy: https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3464